# TypeScript 0.9 Generics: JQueryPromise<T> result compiles to JQueryPromise<any>

Tags: typescript

I am currently using TypeScript 0.9.0.1 and using the JQueryPromise interface when making AJAX calls. I have just started implementing the new generics functionality and noticed I am not getting intellisense when calling a generic function with the type set in the called function.

I would like to call userService.GetRole() and return the type JQueryPromise< Role > but it doesn't in this scenario... it returns JQueryPromise< any > and intellisense doesn't work on the 'role' variable:

```
/// <reference path="../declarations/jquery.d.ts" />

interface Role {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
}

module Services {

    export class UserService {

        //Non-Generic Call
        GetRole<Role>(): JQueryPromise<Role>{
            return $.get('/url');
        }

    }

}

$(function () {

    var userService = new Services.UserService();

    //GetRole() is returning JQueryPromise<any> and not JQueryPromise<Role> as declared
    userService.GetRole().then((role) =>
        //role is inferred as type 'any' and not 'Role' so intellisense does not work
        console.log(role.Name)
    );

});
```

The following does give me intellisense but I would have to type userService.GetRole< Role >() rather than just userService.GetRole():

```
/// <reference path="../declarations/jquery.d.ts" />

interface Role {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
}

module Services {

    export class UserService {

        //Generic Call
        GetRole<T>(): JQueryPromise<T> {
            return $.get('/url');
        }

    }

}

$(function () {

    var userService = new Services.UserService();

    userService.GetRole<Role>().then((role) =>
        //Intellisense now works but I have pass the type '<Role>' every call
        console.log(role.Name)
    );

});
```

So my question is:
**Is there a way to make the call userService.GetRole().then((role) ...etc. with the 'role' parameter recognized as type 'Role'?**

Comment: Shouldn't the non-generic version look like this? `GetRole(): JQueryPromise<Role> { ... }` - also, remember that this is a 0.x version of TypeScript, it probably still contains some bugs in both the compiler and the VS extension.

Comment: Are you using the "official" jquery.d.ts file? It seems like this hasn't been ported to support generics: http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#typings/jquery.d.ts

Comment: @Niko Thanks for the comments. I am using the definitely typed version of jquery.d.ts... it is ported, has the Microsoft license, and assume it is "official" (but not sure/clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends upon the level that you want generics to become active. e.g you can move it to your class:

```
module Services {

    //Generic Class
    export class UserService<T> {    

        GetRole(): JQueryPromise<T> {
            return $.get('/url');
        }    
    }    
}

$(function () {

    var userService = new Services.UserService<Role>();

    // You don't need role in every call anymore 
    userService.GetRole().then((role) =>
        console.log(role.Name)
    );    
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  After fiddling with this after posting I ended moving the type to the class level and seeing this work just as you have noted.